# Journey Builder and Update Contact

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

I am busy building a multi-step welcome journey in SFMC, but some aspects aren't working as expected.

We have an external CRM system that we import data from in to SFMC, where our ConsumerID is set as the SubscriberKey.

I have an automation that selects all new Consumers (based on acquisition date in our CRM) and places them in to a DE that is the source for my journey. That DE is set up in Contact Builder with Contact Key linked to ConsumerID.

I have created a number of DEs to log Consumers that enter and exit the journey (using the Update Contact Event in Journey Builder). These log DEs are set up in Contact Builder as Attribute Groups, and linked to the Contact Key.

The Update Contact Event is configured to update the 'Send_Date' field in my Log DEs, with 'use current date'.

However, when the Update Contact Event triggers, it is loading the email address in to the Log DE, not the ConsumerID.

Contact Builder is a bit confusing, so I am guessing I have set something up incorrectly, but I have no idea what, any ideas?

Thanks!

Source Data Extension:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/2WB32xB.jpg]

Log Data Extension:
[image]

Attribute link in Contact Builder:
[image]

Comment: Please have a check on if your subscriber key(Consumer ID- which should also be the primary key) is mapped to Contact Key in 'All Contacts' under the contact builder.

Comment: I have updated my OP with images, I have already linked the Contact Key to the Consumer_ID field in my source DE>

Comment: Are there any other attribute group that is linking the entry DE or the Log DE?

Comment: There shouldn't be. I created them as sendable data extensions, went in to Contact Builder, clicked 'create attribute group' then did the link, so as far as I understand it, they are only linked to 'Contacts'

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that there may be an issue in the configuration of the Subscriber relationship to All Subscribers for your journey entry data extension. In the properties of this data extension the ConsumerID should be linked to the SubscriberKey. From what you describe it may be possible that the email address is used for this link.

Example (using ContactID instead of ConsumerID):
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my original post to show screenshots, they are already set up as you mention.

Comment: As far as I know this setup should be correct. Are you sure the field 'ConsumerID' in the audience DE doesn't contain email addresses by accident?